# Unable to connect to MongoDB using Spring Boot in Docker-Compose

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run my app and MongoDB containers in Docker Compose, but I get  the following error:

```
2021-03-17 13:30:08.776  INFO 1 --- [l'}-mongo:27018] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongo:27018


com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
app      |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar!/:na]
app      |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar!/:na]
app      |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar!/:na]
app      |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar!/:na]
app      |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app      | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
app      |  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app      |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app      |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app      |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app      |  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app      |  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app      |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar!/:na]
app      |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar!/:na]
app      |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar!/:na]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    hostname: app
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongo
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27018
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=tfood

  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    container_name: mongo
    hostname: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
```

Everyone on the Internet who faced the same problem as me always had some trouble with hostname, what is not my case. From the error log i saw that docker gets the connection data, just couldn't connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exposes port `27018` on the host machine, if you wanted to connect to MongoDB from your Windows/Mac/Linux desktop:

```
  ports:
      - "27018:27017"
```

Inside the Docker network, the port that is exposed to other Docker containers is `27017`. So you need to change this to `27017`:

```
SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
```