# Docker MongoDB - Exception opening socket from containerized Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

Basically, I have Spring Boot app (test-service). When ran outside of a container, it's able to connect to both of my MongoDB instances (non-containerized and containerized). When I run the app from a container, I get an exception.

What doesn't make sense is, when I bash into the container that test-service is running in, I can ping the containerized MongoDB.

This is driving me crazy and I'm probably doing something dumb. Here are copy and paste of relevant snippets. Please help...

**stack trace**

```
test-service  | 2023-04-15 01:31:14.099  INFO 1 --- [}-mongodb:27018] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb:27018
test-service  | 
test-service  | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
test-service  |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
test-service  |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
test-service  |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
test-service  |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
test-service  |        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
test-service  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: mongodb:27018
test-service  |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
test-service  |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
test-service  |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
test-service  |        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
test-service  |        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
test-service  |        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
test-service  |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
test-service  |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
test-service  |        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
test-service  |        ... 4 common frames omitted
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:6.0.5
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test-service
    platform: linux/arm64
  test-service:
    image: test-service:0.1.0
    container_name: test-service
    volumes:
      - $HOME/config/keystore:/var/keystore
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      MONGO_HOST: mongodb
      MONGO_PORT: 27018
      MONGO_USER: admin
      MONGO_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_AUTH_DB: admin
      KEYSTORE_PATH: /var/keystore/dev-env-cert.p12
    platform: linux/arm64
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
volumes:
  mongodb: {}
```

**application.properties**

```
mongodb.host=${MONGO_HOST:localhost}
mongodb.port=${MONGO_PORT:27017}
mongodb.database=test-service
mongodb.authentication-database=${MONGO_AUTH_DB:admin}
mongodb.username=${MONGO_USER:admin}
mongodb.password=${MONGO_PASSWORD:admin}
```

**Mongo config (java code)**
I've tried messing around with different ways to configure the MongoDB connection, this is my latest...

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    @Value("${mongodb.host}")
    private String dbHost;
    @Value("${mongodb.port}")
    private String dbPort;
    @Value("${mongodb.authentication-database}")
    private String dbAuthDb;
    @Value("${mongodb.username}")
    private String dbUsername;
    @Value("${mongodb.password}")
    private String dbPassword;
    @Value("${mongodb.database}")
    private String dbName;

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return dbName;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.test.model";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings
            .builder()
            .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString("mongodb://" + dbHost + ":" 
                + dbPort + "/" + dbName))
            .credential(MongoCredential.createScramSha256Credential(dbUsername, 
                dbAuthDb, dbPassword.toCharArray()))
            .applicationName(dbName)
            .build();
        MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings);

        return client;
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I want to mention that I've also checked the container's admin DB, tried granting additional roles, and tested with another "test" user, but still no luck

```
admin> db.getUsers()
{
  users: [
    {
      _id: 'admin.admin',
      userId: new UUID("8730bf38-301c-4123-a8a3-1c651d7b1e4e"),
      user: 'admin',
      db: 'admin',
      roles: [
        { role: 'dbOwner', db: 'test-service' },
        { role: 'root', db: 'admin' }
      ],
      mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
    },
    {
      _id: 'admin.test',
      userId: new UUID("fb16d8e3-537b-4f67-a6fc-2b22faf6f242"),
      user: 'test',
      db: 'admin',
      roles: [ { role: 'dbOwner', db: 'test-service' } ],
      mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
    }
  ],
  ok: 1
}
```

Comment: My assumption your problem in `mongoClient` function. Try to return the URI hardcoded. as you can see `Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb:27018` application does not go to `localhost`

Comment: @4EACH Ok, i'll give this a try when I get back later tonight. Although, I don't see why I'd want it to point to ```localhost``` when ```mongodb``` is the service name of the MongoDB container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong and yes I was being stupid...

Issue was just the port. If you look at my compose file, under the mongodb service I have this

```
ports:
  - "27018:27017"
```

and my test-service service has this

```
environment:
  MONGO_HOST: mongodb
  MONGO_PORT: 27018
```

mongodb service exposes port 27017 in the container environment, while 27018 for the host environment. test-service service lives in the container environment, so I should've been using 27017. As soon as I changed that, everything worked.

Credit to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66674449/2963004). I found it while Googling last night...